# Gnuplot time range limit

Tags: gnuplot

```
$data << EOD
1563619139 10
1532083139 9
1500547139 8
1469011139 7
1437388739 6
1405852739 5
1374316739 4
1342780739 3
1311158339 2
1279622339 1
EOD

set terminal png
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x '%Y'
unset key
plot '$data' u 1:2
```

[image: Numbers over the last ten years]

How do I plot values only from say 2015? I tried `plot ["2015":] '$data' u 1:2` via the [docs](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node143.html) but it doesn't work as expected.

I realise I could edit $data, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an older an a newer gnuplot syntax for timedata.
The example below uses the newer syntax.
Check `help time/date`, `help timecolumn`, and `help strptime`.

**Code:**

```
### time data
reset session

$Data << EOD
1563619139 10
1532083139 9
1500547139 8
1469011139 7
1437388739 6
1405852739 5
1374316739 4
1342780739 3
1311158339 2
1279622339 1
EOD

unset key
set format x "%Y" time

StartTime = strptime("%Y","2015")   # 2015-01-01 00:00:00 in seconds after 1970
set xrange[StartTime:]
set xtics StartTime, 3600*24*365    # start time and major tic distance one year in seconds

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,"%s")):2 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same format of `timefmt` to specify the range.

```
plot ["1420092000":] '$data' u 1:2
```

The seconds in Gnuplot are measured starting from 1970.
I calculated the starting time considering 365.25 days in a year, hence 1420092000 s, but using `strptime("%Y","2015")`, as reported in the other answer, is without doubt more correct and precise.
You can add

```
set xtics 31557600
```

to have only major tics corresponding to the beginning of year. The value specified is the time increment between tics that must be given in seconds.

Comment: Ah, so 31557600 is a year?

Comment: I set the step to 365.25*24*60*60.